# Force Facebook Sharing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to modify this code, but I need help.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#fblogin').click(function (event) {
                @if($json_cu_variabile['fbappid'] == 'YOUR APP ID')
                alert('PLEASE SET FACEBOOK APP ID');
                @else
                doLogin(event);
                @endif

            });

            $('#tryagain').click(function () {
                window.location.href = "{{ $appname }}";
            });
        });
        //call this on user interaction (click)
        function doLogin(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,age_range,locale'}, function (response) {
                        var locale = response.locale,
                                email = response.email,
                                fbid = response.id,
                                name = response.name,
                                firstname = response.first_name,
                                lastname = response.last_name,
                                gender = response.gender;

                        var formData = {
                            "appname": '{{ $appname }}',
                            "locale": locale,
                            "email": email,
                            "fbid": fbid,
                            "name": name,
                            "firstname": firstname,
                            "lastname": lastname,
                            "gender": gender
                        };

                        formData = JSON.stringify(formData);

                        $("body").data("fbid", fbid).data("name", name);


                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'generate',
                            contentType: 'text/plain',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cache: false,

                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $('.blog-post').hide();
                                $('.result-loader').show();
                            },

                            success: function (data) {
                                $("body").data('shareUrl', data.share_url).data('shareImage', data.share_image);

                                $('#resultimage, #share-modal-image').attr('src', '{{ url() }}/{{ $appname }}/master-image?fbid=' + fbid + '&gender=' + gender + '&fullname=' + name + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&result=' + data.randomresult + '');

                                var loadImage = new Image();
                                loadImage.src = $('#resultimage').attr('src');
                                loadImage.onload = function () {
                                    $('.result-loader').hide();
                                    $('#showresult').fadeIn(800);
                                    generatedCount();
                                    @if(!empty($json_cu_variabile['disp-share-modal']) && $json_cu_variabile['disp-share-modal'] == 'on')
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                                $('#shareModal').modal('show');
                                            }, {{ $json_cu_variabile['modal-time'] }}000);
                                    @endif


                                };
                            },

                            error: function () {

                            }
                        });

                        return false;


                    });
                } else {
                    //   console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {scope: 'public_profile, publish_actions, user_friends, email'});
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '{{ $json_cu_variabile['fbappid'] }}',
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.7'
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook,
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                }
            });
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        $('#fblogin').click(function () {
            var y = $(".blog-main").offset().top;
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: y - 65}, 600);
        });


        var $body = $("body");

        function shareOnFB() {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                link: $body.data('shareUrl'),
                @if($fbimage == 'generatedimage')
                picture: $body.data('shareImage'),
                @else
                picture: '{{ url($appimage) }}',    
                @endif
                redirect_uri: '{{ url() }}',
            }, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error_code) {
                    $('#share-link').click();
                    $('#shareModal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        }

        $body.data("appname", "{{ $appname }}");
    </script>

    <script src="{{ URL::asset('admin/js/sharecnt.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('admin/js/generated-count.js') }}"></script>
```

I get a share through modal.

My intent is to replace the modal with a forced share through the publish_actions...

It would be interesting if opened a modal with two options. Asking if the visitor would like to start the test without sharing or want to start the test and share. All of this, using the publish_actions permission.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are not allowed to force users to share. You should go read https://developers.facebook.com/policy before you proceed.

Comment: Speech mode ... wanted an option to share with a click, which used the publish_actions permission. I can pay anyone who can help me with this implementation.